# two models in rails and how to bring them together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a simple project with Rails 4. I have two models right now-Author and Books. I currently have it so that the models look like this:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

author controller looks like this:

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController

def index 
  @authors = Author.all
  @book = Book.find(params[:author_id])
  (Not sure if the @book line is right)
end
```

My schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "genre"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

I have it so that my books index.html.erb I can see the author who wrote the book. For example: <%= book.author.name %>. That works just as I want it to. Now what I want to do, on my author index.html.erb page, is show all of the books that belong to an author.

On the author's index.html.erb page I have the following:

```
<h1>All Authors</h1>
<p><%= link_to "New", new_author_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @authors.each do |author| %>
      <h1><%= author.name %></h1>
      <p><%= author.book.title %></p>
      <%= link_to "Show", author_path(author), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_author_path(author), class: "btn btn-warning"    
      %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", author_path(author), method: :delete, data: {   
      confirm: "Are you Sure?" }, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The main line that I need help with, I believe, is the following: 
<%= author.book.title %> Again, my main question is how do I get it so that on my authors index page I see all of the books that they wrote? Is nesting my routes, like this:

```
  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
  end
```

Or is there another way? Thank you for any help and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: instead of use `author.book` you should loop through each author's books using `author.books`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would loop through the books as such:

```
<h1>All Authors</h1>
<p><%= link_to "New", new_author_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @authors.each do |author| %>
      <h1><%= author.name %></h1>
      <% author.books.each do |book| %>
        <p><%= book.title %></p>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "Show", author_path(author), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_author_path(author), class: "btn btn-warning"    
      %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", author_path(author), method: :delete, data: {   
      confirm: "Are you Sure?" }, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The above would work, but it's not efficient as it would result in a (N+1) query.

A way to work around this is:

In your controller,

```
def index
  @authors = Author.includes(:books)
end
```

This would still slow down your database, but adding a limit and paginating may help to fix that.